# If an integer a is such that a-2 is divisible by 3 then a^2-1 is divisible by 3. prove by direct method

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How to prove that if a is number such that $a-2$ is divisible by $3$ then $a^2-1$ is divisible by $3$ using direct method.

I know if $a = 2$ then $a-2 = 0$ is divisible by $3$ and $2^2-1 = 3$ is divisible by $3$ but how to prove it using direct method.

Comment: Hint: $a^2-1=(a-2)(a+2)+3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)=(a-1)(a-2+3)=(a-1)(a-2)+3(a-1)$$

So, $a^2-1$ will be divisible by $3$ if $a-1$ or $a-2$ is so

Comment: @Downvoter, would you mind sharing the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We're given

$$a-2=3k\iff a= 2+3k\implies a^2-1=(a+1)(a-1)=(3+3k)(a-1)=3(1+k)(a-1)\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ 3\mid \color{#c00}{a-2}\ \Rightarrow\ 3\mid\!\! \overbrace{a+1}^{\large \ \color{#c00}{a-2}\,+\,3}\!\!\mid a^2-1$

Answer (score 0):

$$
a^{2} - 1 = \left(a - 2\right)^{2} + 4\left(a - 2\right) + 3
$$

Answer (score 0):

In mod $3$, since 
$$a-2\equiv 0\iff a\equiv 2,$$
$$a^2-1\equiv 2^2-1=3\equiv 0.$$

Comment: If the OP knew even very basic modular arithmetic his question would be completely trivial...

Comment: hmm, I agree with you, but I hope this might be the first step for the OP to learn it...

Answer (score 0):

If $a-2$ is divisible by $k$, then $a-2=3k$. So $a=2+3k$ and $a^2-1=4+9k^2+12k-1=3+9k^2+12k=3(1+3k^2+4k)$ so it's divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$a-2=3k\Rightarrow a-1=3k+1\Rightarrow a+1=3(k+1)\text { and } a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$

Can you conclude?

Comment: yes i can do that thank you.